# Loop through object fields in firestore with Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document. It has a bunch of object fields in "products"
How do I loop through this dictionary?

```
let dict = doc.data()

for (key,value) in dict["products"]{

}
```

This gives me the error:

> Type 'Any?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

What is my obvious problem?

EDIT: The docs say

```
/**
* Retrieves all fields in the document as an `NSDictionary`.
*
* @return An `NSDictionary` containing all fields in the document.
*/
- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)data;
```

Comment: Can you share with us what `doc.data()` returns actually?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
let dict = doc.data()

if let products = dict["products"] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {

    for (key,value) in products {

    }
}
```

`doc.data()` returns `Any?`, so in order to treat it as a `Dictionary` you need to cast it to `Dictionary`.

Comment: Keys in the dictionary don't have to be of type `String` all the time. You should check for `Hashable` instead like `as? [Hashable: Any]`.

Comment: What is the error?
I updated the code so we're now iterating through the elements of the returned dictionary, which may contain another dictionary as the value for "product" key.

Comment: error: Using 'Hashable' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Hashable' is not supported

Comment: If you're sure the returned dictionary's keys are of type `String` then replace `Hashable` with `String`.

Comment: @jimijon If you're not sure, then check my updated answer.

Comment: your updated compiles but gives a warning:  Conditional cast from '[String : Any]' to '[AnyHashable : AnyObject]' always succeeds